# public assets folder is not included in asset pipeline to render data properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables

Public assets folder is not being included in assets to render the data. dataTables is in public/assets/dataTables folder.

this is application.css file

```
/*
*= require jquery.ui.core
*= require jquery.ui.theme
*= require jquery.dataTables
*= require_self
*= require_tree
*/
```

this is application.js file

```
//= require  prototype
//= require  effects
//= require  dragdrop
//= require  controls
////= require  calendarview
//= require  rails
//= require_self
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
```

and application.rb file is

```
 module RailsAppAdminNew
  class Application < Rails::Application    
    config.time_zone = 'Islamabad'
    config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Islamabad'
    config.encoding = "utf-8"
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]            
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/config/common_messages)

    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/config/messages) #{config.root}/app/local_models #{config.root}/local_lib %W(#{config.root}/lib))

    config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
    config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/config/common_messages/*"]
    config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/config/messages/*"]    
    config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/local_models/*"]    
    config.eager_load_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/local_models)
    config.log_level = :debug
    config.assets.enabled = true
    config.serve_static_assets = false   
    config.assets.version = '1.0'    
    config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(application.js rails.js)

  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have `config.serve_static_assets = false` when it should be set to `true`.

From http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html:

> `config.serve_static_assets` configures Rails itself to serve static
>   assets. Defaults to  true, but in the production environment is turned
>   off as the server software (e.g. Nginx or Apache) used to run the
>   application should serve static assets instead. Unlike the default
>   setting set this to true when running (absolutely not recommended!) or
>   testing your app in production mode using WEBrick. Otherwise you won´t
>   be able use page caching and requests for files that exist regularly
>   under the public directory will anyway hit your Rails app.

Comment: To further build on this, the default production.rb configuration yields the setting for this to an ENV variable.

`config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?`